# Why can't I create new classes in AX any more?

Tags: class, save, axapta

I created a new class in AX. After an AX restart the class was no longer in the AOT. If I now try to create a new class I get this error message:

"Unable to save . Unable to save Class Class2. Id 50001 already exists."

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a data corruption in your .aod or .aoi index.

Select Reindex from Tools\Development tools\Application objects.
This will recreate the .aoi file and this may solve your problem.

The reindex operation may take several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you Just close the services of Ax and delete the .aoi file.
then restart the services.
now try to create class.
Thanks and Regards,
Deepak Kumar